# How to use Java RabbitMQ and set URI server?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using the RabbitMQ Java API to connect to a RabbitMQ server. I want to use `ConnectionFactory.setUri(...)` to configure which server to use. It appears to munge the virtual host.

There's a default virtual host named `/`.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

import java.net.URI;

public class Worker {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        final URI uri = URI.create("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/");
        factory.setUri(uri);
        final Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    }
}
```

Using the above code, the configured virtual host is empty. There doesn't seem to be a way, using the URI, to configure the virtual host to be `/`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up solving this by not using `setUri` but rather setting the individual URI components.

Comment: I tried with the following (appending another slash at the end): `amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//` and ended up getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple segments in path of AMQP URI: //`. I guess for now the only way is to use the factory methods to set the parameters like you've done.

Answer (score 5):

Your need to URL-encode the '/' using %2F

Answer (score 4):

For people coming from google, using the combination of `/` and the url encoded `/` which is `%2f`, worked for me.

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2F");
```