# Connecting to / vhost with factory.setUri() in rabbitmq

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I have connection code:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri(System.getenv("CLOUDAMQP_URL"));
```

but I get an error:

```
23:16:24 web.1    | started with pid 3098
23:16:27 web.1    | Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:378)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:621)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:648)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at Main.run(Main.java:212)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at Main.main(Main.java:239)
23:16:27 web.1    | Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
23:16:27 web.1    |     ... 5 more
23:16:27 web.1    | Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
23:16:27 web.1    |     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:536)
23:16:27 web.1    |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
23:16:27 web.1    | exited with code 1
23:16:27 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

and my rabbit logs show a connection denial

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Jul-2015::23:16:27 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.9858.0> (127.0.0.1:38856 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_error,opening,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "access to vhost '' refused for user 'guest'",
                             'connection.open'}}
```

how do I connect to the default vhost (/) using setUri?  The [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221874/how-to-use-java-rabbitmq-and-set-uri-server) this question was asked, the asker's solution was to not use setUri.  What is the uri way?

Annoyingly, the same URI works with pika; is there a difference in how the two implementions (python and java) parse URIs?

EDIT:  The URL I am using is

```
CLOUDAMQP_URL=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with authorization and not with `setUri` method. What is the value of `CLOUDAMQP_URL`? Have you specified correct login and password? Maybe there is no access for `guest` user on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an variance with how the URI is parsed in [the source](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/master/src/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java#L239).  In particular, the URI is split on /s then URLdecoded; this means that my URI (`amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/`) returns the empty string for the vhost (instead of the default / [like python does).](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/2cd8572c6247ef6507b3a7165056063716d769eb/pika/connection.py#L479)  I got around this by using

```
factory.setUri(System.getenv("CLOUDAMQP_URL"));
factory.setVirtualHost("/");
```

to overwrite the inferred wrong value, but this is bad solution.  Another working solution is to change the URL:

```
CLOUDAMQP_URL=amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2F
```

Note the URLencoded / via **%2F**.  I will open an issue/PR with the library, because the python solution seems more intuitive.

EDIT: I spoke with the library maintainers.  They note that they are the authoritative implementation, and that pika is doing something outside [the spec](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html) (see appendix A).  It is unfortunate that the stock rabbit implementation (with a vhost of "/") is incompatible with the stock java rabbit mq client's interpretation of the default URI, but so it is.  Use the %2F fix.